# Webdriver hangs on before switching to pop up window

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to switch between windows
for popup i am using java script executor to open it :

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)(oASelFW.driver);
String elem = "parent.callFunction('yfcFireAction','WSIYOML030A11');";
js.executeScript(el‌​em,"");
```

after that web driver is not executing next lines of code , when  perform some operations in popup the execution continues normally!

don't know what to do.totally stuck up

Any help would be thankful!

Comment: Can you please post the code you have tried so far

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the code snippet illustrated the problem. Thanks!

Comment: JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)(oASelFW.driver);String elem="parent.callFunction('yfcFireAction','WSIYOML030A11');";js.executeScript(elem,"");

Comment: the above code opens a popup window but after that webdriver hangs on it even doesn't throw any error in eclipse console

Comment: i tried upgrading iedriver to latest version but still facing the same problem no luck :(

Comment: @Sriram any help would be really help me a lot

Comment: Moved in question code that author posted as a comment

Comment: have you tried switching to Alert ?